# How to notate a While loop?

Tags: summation

I've noticed that Sigma notation is a lot like a For loop in programming. What, if anything, can be used to notate a While loop mathematically?

In other words, how to you notate the sum of everything (like Sigma) while a variable is equal or unequal to a certain number or expression?

Comment: Check this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392375/turn-while-loop-into-math-equation

Comment: You can try to describe the process like a distribution of probability or an integral. You can express conditions under a lot of functions like Kronecker delta. If you want Kronecker delta under some analytic you can try use the condition as the limit of a function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not uncommon to have notation like $$\sum_{i\in S} f(i)$$
where $S$ is some set of indices for $i$.  Also common is $$\sum_{i\ge 100,\  i\notin S} g(i)$$
where two conditions are combined, and only indices satisfying both are used.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it appears to be what I am looking for. However, I am still slightly unlearned to the complete functionality of Sigma notation. Could you give me an example of these two situations so I can see them in action?

Comment: You could define $S=\{2k+1:k\in\mathbb{N}\}$, the set of all odd indices.  You could define $S=\{p\in\mathbb{N}:p\text{ is prime }\}$.  Any way you like!

Comment: @NickSuwyn Lets say you want to count all primes less than $n$. If $\mathbb P$ is the set of all primes then you can do the following: $$\sum_{p<n,\,p\in\mathbb P}1$$Simmilarily if you want the sum of primes less than $n$ you can do this$$\sum_{p<n,\,p\in\mathbb P}p$$

Answer (score 3):

A while loop cant be directly written in mathematical notation, however every while loop can be written as a recursive function.

If we have the while loop below, which changes all the variables each iteration using a function for each variable.

```
a = initial value for a
b = initial value for b
...
while (expression) {
  a = na(a,b,...)
  b = nb(a,b,...)
  ...
}
```

This can be written as a recursive function as below:

```
function(a,b,...) {
  if (expression) {
    return a
  } else {
    a_new = na(a,b,...)
    b_new = nb(a,b,...)
    ...
    return function(a_new,b_new,...)
  }
}
```

A recursive function can easily be written in mathematical notation

$$
f(a,b,\dots)=
\begin{cases}
a\quad&\text{if expression}\\
f(n_a(a,b,\dots),n_b(a,b,\dots),\dots)&\text{if not expression}
\end{cases}
$$

Very often it is possible to write a recursive formula like this one as a sum or product, in which case it is often better to do so.

---

Examble based on [your other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1284088/132791).

In your other question, you could explain the sum (up to some constant N) as the following while loop:

```
sum = 0
summand = x
iterations_left = N
while (iterations_left > 0) {
  summand = summand / 2
  sum = sum + summand
  iterations_left = iterations_left - 1
}
```

This can be written as a recursive function the following way:

```
sum_to(x, iterations) {
  if (iterations == 1) {
    return x/2
  } else {
    return x/2 + sum_to(x/2, iterations - 1)
  }
}
```

And can such be written as a recursive function

$$
f(x,i)=
\begin{cases}
x/2\quad&\text{if }i=1\\
x/2+f(x/2,i-1)&\text{if }i\ne1
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: I like this, I am going to look into it a little further tomorrow. Thank you for the response!