# How to write for / while loop in mathematical notation

Tags: functions, notation

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1284157/how-to-notate-a-while-loop) they suggest $$\sum_{i\in S} f(i)$$

I just wanted to clarify if it is okay to notate a while loop like this, where the while loop would be simply looping until some condition is met, executing a function.

```
b = 10
while (a < b) {
  x()
  a++
}
```

or even

```
while (true) {
  x()
  // ...
  if (something) break
}
```

or wondering if it would also work for a for loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  x()
}
```

where none of these functions actually create a sum explicitly, but instead execute a function some number of times.

Comment: Assuming that $x$ is a function, your first example is essentially $x^{10}$, i.e. the $10$-fold composition of $x$ with itself.  Your second example comes down to the same thing (in mathematics, we don't typically "test" for truthiness in our notation, because statements are either true or false *a priori*).  The last bit of pseudocode is basically the same as the first (I don't see the distinction).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In pure math, functions don't have "side-effects". Variables are not updated; they are either set to a specific value, or they range over all values simultaneously: there *is no "updating", because there is no "time"*. So, under the strictest possible interpretation, this question doesn't make sense.

To talk about the effects of code purely mathematically, you effectively need to find a way to express it without directly talking about 'time'. The easiest way to do this is to use a recursive definition.

For instance, if `x` is something like:

```
if(p(a))
  a = f(a);
else
  a = a+1;
```

then you might turn that into a sequence, and write:

> Let $a_0 =$ *[some starting value]* . For all natural numbers $n>0$, define $a_n$ as:
>
> $$a_n = \begin{cases}f(a_{n-1}) & \text{if }p(a) \\ a_{n-1} + 1 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Then, you can 'access' the value of `a` after calling `x` 10 times by just writing $a_{10}$.

---

...or you can just write some pseudocode, and say "let $a_i$ be the value of `a` after $i$ iterations of `x`". As long as you make it clear what you're doing (and as long as your audience knows any programming at all), you should be able to get your point across.